# Finding which child is using up all my memory in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I am troubleshooting a crashing Erlang program.  It runs out of memory.  It has several children started by OTP (`one_for_one` in the supervisor), and some started with `spawn`.

I am starting the program and falling into the Erlang prompt `(test@test)1>`.  I'd like to see how much memory each of these children is using from here.  I've searched online and not found anything, but this seems like a common enough need to already have a solution.

How can I find the memory utilization of each child, in Erlang, from the system prompt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try observer?

when you get the prompt, type observer:start(), then in the Application tab, you can see all the applications for each of them the processes. For each process you can get the memory usage by opening the process_info sub window.

Answer (score 2):

Try erlang:process_info/2 with memory in ItemList

```
process_info(Pid, ItemList) -> InfoTupleList | [] | undefined
Types
Pid = pid()
ItemList = [Item]
Item = process_info_item()
InfoTupleList = [InfoTuple]
InfoTuple = process_info_result_item()
process_info_item() = 
backtrace |
binary |
catchlevel |
current_function |
current_location |
current_stacktrace |
dictionary |
error_handler |
garbage_collection |
garbage_collection_info |
group_leader |
heap_size |
initial_call |
links |
last_calls |
memory |
message_queue_len |
messages |
min_heap_size |
min_bin_vheap_size |
monitored_by |
monitors |
message_queue_data |
priority |
reductions |
registered_name |
sequential_trace_token |
stack_size |
status |
suspending |
total_heap_size |
trace |
trap_exit
```